# What is the proper way to get values from Checkboxes generated in a Razor loop in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm desperately trying to understand how this is supposed to be accomplished without hacking about in Javascript...

The requirement is as follows: -

- A page, with a 'User Selection' drop down at the top.
- Underneath is a collection of Checkboxes with what Permission Claims are available within the system...

-- A user is selected, the checkboxes are checked where necessary (if that user has that claim or not...)

-- You are able to check the boxes on/off as required, then click the save button and it post all the claim checkbox states back for that user to the controller, then go off and add them to that user where necessary etc...

I've been through several versions of trying to get this to work now without just hoovering everything up in javascript and simply posting it back to the controller after heavily processing it client side in a way that the controller can just be spoon-fed the final data. (or is this the best way?)

What I expected to be able to do is this: -

Using Razor, generate the checkboxes on initial page load, the drop down has an initial selected item of 'Select User' so nothing is checked on first page load...

Then, a user is selected, I expected to be able to make the dropdown submit back to the controller, identify in the controller that it's the Drop down and not the save button, then return the model with the Selected bools set accordingly for each checkbox data item within the collection of claims...

I then expect to click the checkboxes as needed and submit the whole model back with the save button and in the controller work out the differences just by looking at the Claims collection in the model with it's now updated 'Selected' values..?

[image]

But this isn't how it works is it... :(

Anyone got any suggestions how to do this 'properly'?

Comment: Can you add a snapshot of page how it looks

Comment: @Saineshwar Done :)